# My data is not being displayed in my TTTableViewController subclass. Why not?

Tags: three20

Here's the background: I'm initializing and setting the dataSource in my `TTTableViewController` like so:

```
- (void)createModel {
    TTSectionedDataSource *dataSource = [[[TTSectionedDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
    dataSource.model = [[[LogsModel alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

The model is a `TTURLRequestModel`, so when the response is returned from the model, I set the dataSource's items and sections in my `TTTableViewController` like so:

```
- (void)modelDidFinishLoad:(id<TTModel>)model {
    ((TTSectionedDataSource *)self.dataSource).items = ((LogsModel *)model).items;
    ((TTSectionedDataSource *)self.dataSource).sections = ((LogsModel *)model).sections;
    [super modelDidFinishLoad:model];
}
```

This issue came up when I switched from using hard-coded data in my model to actually making a request to the web service. What am I doing wrong? Am I creating the model incorrectly? Or setting the items & sections on the dataSource in the wrong place? Any thoughts or comments are welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the reason for this. In my model class (LogsModel for the code above), I implemented the `- (BOOL)isLoaded` method when I was using hard-coded data. When I switched to making requests to the web service, my implementation of `isLoaded` happened to return NO all the time, so the TTTableViewController wasn't showing my data. I removed my implementation of `- (BOOL)isLoaded`, and the problem was solved.

Comment: can you show how you implemented the isLoaded method, because i think my problem is similar with this.

Comment: @Bacalso Vincent - I updated my answer. The solution is to remove any custom implementation of `-(BOOL)isLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at the three20's twitter demo app (TTTwitter). Three20 has a simplified way on separating the models / data source and tables.

The controller should only create the datasource, without "knowing" about the items and sections:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 - (void)createModel {
 self.dataSource = [[[TTTwitterSearchFeedDataSource alloc]
                  initWithSearchQuery:@"three20"] autorelease];
}
```